# camel-jetty http proxy taking too much time for large request streams (file upload)

Tags: file-upload, apache-camel, jetty, http-proxy, jbossfuse

I have created a camel-jetty http proxy bridge for my project's restful services for document download/upload. These services are invoked to get/upload documents of different types, most of the times the file size is more than 100MB.

When I invoke the upload rest service(HTTP POST) directly(not routing it via camel-jetty http proxy) to upload the document of 100MB it only takes around 2-3 mins to complete the upload and receive the response back however when I route the request via camel route it takes more than 15 mins which is kind of weird as the camel route in play is nothing but a HTTP proxy.

Following are some info:

**Camel Version**: **2.15.1**

**Camel Route definition**:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8383/sqidds/document?disableStreamCache=true&amp;matchOnUriPrefix=true&amp;enableMultipartFilter=false&amp;continuationTimeout=-1" />
        <log id="incomingMessage" message="incomingMessage - \n[id = ${id}]\n [headers = ${headers}]" />
        <to uri="jetty:http://somehost:8080/sqidds/document?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false&amp;httpClient.timeout=3200000" />
        <log id="outgoingMessage" message="outgoingMessage - \n[id = ${id}]\n [headers = ${headers}]" />
    </route>
```

**Camel Project POM Excerpt:**

```
    .
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-621084</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-621084</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-621084</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-621084</version>
        <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    .
```

**Rest Service(Spring MVC) Code**:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String saveFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException, DocumentNotSavedException {

    String targetPath = null;
    if (file != null) {
        String repoDirectoryPath = "SOME_REPO_PATH";        
        String uniqueFileName = FileUtil.getUniqueFileName(repoDirectoryPath, file.getOriginalFilename());
        File targetFile = new File(repoDirectoryPath, uniqueFileName);
        targetPath = targetFile.getCanonicalPath();

        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getInputStream(), targetFile);

    } else {
        log.error("File is null");
        throw new DocumentNotSavedException("File data could not be saved");
    }

    return targetPath;
}
```

**RestClient Code**:

```
public String putDocument(File file,String fileName) throws RestClientException{
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("SOME_100MB_FILE.pdf");
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
            ByteArrayResource contentsAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(fileBytes, fileName) {
                @Override
                public String getFilename() {
                    return this.getDescription();
                }
            };
            map.add("file", contentsAsResource);
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, httpHeaders);

            response = restTemplate.exchange(serverUri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in put document service", e);
            throw new RestClientException("Exception in put document service :",e);
        }
        return response.getBody();
}
```

**NOTE:** For a 100MB file, the camel route log for incoming message is logged within a sec after the service is invoked, however I see the outgoing log after around 15 mins. I think there might be something wrong with the producer camel route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an improvement in the camel 2.17.0 which can [use response input stream directly in http producer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7638).

Can you try out the latest Camel 2.17.x release (2.17.3) with your route?